# one of my Activity as dialog's buttons not appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In creating Activity as dialog, I used the Relative layout with 2 textView and 2 Buttons .. the textView under each other and the two button next of each other under the textViews
the problem is, one of buttons not appear in the run, but both appear in the preview .. can someone correct me?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".Pop">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="msg title"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="msg"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:text="Not me"
        android:textColor="@color/red"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:text="Yes, I'm"
        android:textColor="#4CAF50">
    </Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

the preview:

[image]

the run:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".PopUp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="msg title"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="msg"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="15dp"></TextView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not me"
            android:textColor="@color/red"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes, I'm"
            android:textColor="#4CAF50"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons' width is set to match_parent, replace with wrap_content, and align the second button 'relative' to the first with android:layout_toEndOf

```
   *android:layout_width="match_parent"*
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
```

Or use a weighted linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    gravity="end">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

But then again nested layouts are discouraged for performance issues. Therefore look into constraint layout to give you the flexibility you need for all your layouts.

But if you are trying to show a dialog, you could just use native AlertDialog which you can add negative and positive buttons to.
Also use start instead of right, like alignParentStart for lollipop (API level 21) and later. Also be careful with hard coding margin in a dialog.

Edit
If you want button to each take half of half the width. Then set their layout_weight to 0.25 or just a quarter of linear layout weightSum, then set gravity to end

Comment: by using weighted linear layout the two buttons become next each other in the right half side